# How can i convert ISO 639 language code to full english name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iso

I am looking for the any way to convert the ISO 639 code to the full english name.

WiKi URL [ISO_639](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639)

Thanks

Comment: Why not a simple dictionary: `@{@"en": @"English", @"fr": @"French", …}`

Comment: I am looking for the stradand way i don't want to miss any language..

Answer (score 1):

Just map them:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Note that sometimes there are two values for Chinese, traditional and simplified.

Comment: thank thats useful for me